# How to prove that a server is running a certain code

Tags: security, hash, deployment, devops

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can clarify.

How can I prove that a certain piece of code is running in a server?

One could create and publish the hash of the code that was deployed on a server, but, on the other hand, I do not seem to find any mechanism of **proving** it.

I believe that PaaS like Heroku or maybe Amazon tackles that problem, at least partially. When one is deploying an application, Heroku returns the git commit hash that references the deployed code. Of course, the code running **might not effectively** be the one disclosed.

Do we have a mechanism for returning a hash of deployment, some sort of summary with code + metadata, and not necessarily a commit hash?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is effectively impossible. The server can run any code, and can report any integrity information (eg. a hash).

Comment: As you said, the code running might not effectively be the one disclosed. Period. PaaS can probably do it, but it basically moves the issue: you now have to trust the PaaS and not the app developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Here's a scenario:

1. Server is running X.
2. Client asks server for proof of code.
3. Server provides proof that the code running is X. Client accepts the proof.
4. A malicious agent redeploys the server with code Y.
5. Session continues, attacker steals data.
6. Session ends.
7. Attacker redeploys the server with code X.

Note that the TCP session on the server side is usually nginx or some such, which also handles TLS termination, so redeploying doesn't even break the client's TCP or TLS session.

Moreover, the server has a runtime, be it the C standard library, node.js, or JVM - how do you know that *that* isn't compromised?

Moreover, even if the server code is correct, the server uses OS resources like networking, disk etc. - how do you know that *those* aren't compromised?

It's hard enough for the server to know it's compromised, it's downright impossible for the client.

Comment: BTW, there's a mechanism called [remote attestation](https://insights.samsung.com/2017/10/03/making-remote-attestation-part-of-your-security-strategy/). It's not feasible to use it to implement a random web app, but interesting nontheless.

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios, it may be practical to write your code as a R1CS circuit and give a succinct zero-knowlege proof that it was executed correctly. This can be done with libraries such as [Circom](https://github.com/iden3/circom), [Zokrates](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates), and [Noir](https://noir-lang.github.io/book/index.html), although it will require learning a new domain-specific language unless you use [Keelung](https://www.btq.com/en/blog/hello-keelung) in Haskell.

The tradeoff will be:

- a slower runtime, which may render some use cases impractical
- requirement that all inputs to your program are either a fixed length or are padded to a fixed length.

But it will enable you to prove that you executed certain code correctly without any trust gaurantees.