# Is it possible to create OPEN BACKEND? for example written on python

Tags: python, httprequest, backend

I mean when anybody can check how backend work, but nobody can change the backend.

That's for purpose to prove users that there is no any cheating on server.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> when anybody can check how backend work

do you mean anyone can look at the code of the backend? That's certainly possible, and it can be done without compromising the security of the application.

There are plenty of secure backends and libraries that are published in open source repositories.

Assuming that you don't share private keys or other sensitive data, and your backend is built with modern security principles in mind, it should be possible to allow others to read the backend without risking the safety of your application/data.

Comment: So, but how to prove users that the code I show them is the really code that is on server?

Comment: do you mean anyone can look at the code of the backend? Yes.

Comment: how to prove that the server I show is the really server the requests sends to?

Comment: It's not really possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701633/3587606